# loop not working when nested?

Tags: bash, logs

my code below as you see is clear, the inner loop seems to work, but when nested under another, it doesn't, (`no idea why`)

Idea is to iterate variables `a` `b` with while1 and hand it over to while2, the while2 is waiting for a line in log_file to appear for the case statement to execute.

It does not work with actual process and it's real log_file

```
#!/bin/bash

bi_log='/var/log/process/process.log'
bi_conf='/etc/process/process.conf'

cat input_file | while
    read a b
do
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        case $line in
            "Processing Data ended*"* )        echo "Found" &&
                                               echo $a $b >> $bi_conf
                                               ;;
        esac
        sleep 1
        break
    done < <(tail -n0 -f $bi_log)
done
```

Looks like inner loop workin fine, but maybe something seems wrong with nesting it under outer one.
variables `a` & `b` are not echoed out to file.

Comment: You used `bi_conf` instead of `$bi_conf`

Comment: @muru ok it was typo while pasting here, but I tried that too, problem is only echo wouldn't work either: `echo $a $b` so I get text "Found" but not variables from first loop. my BASH_VERSION: 4.2.46(2)-release

Comment: `break` exits the nearest enclosing loop. To break out of both nested loops, you need `break 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your script, starting with the fact that the `tail -n0 -f $bi_log` is never going to exit, so the outer loop will never get to the second line of `input_file`.

Try something more like this:

```bsh
while read -r a b ; do
  tail -n0 -f "$bi_log" | 
    awk -v a="$a" -v b="$b" \
      '/Processing Data ended/ {
         print "found" > /dev/stderr;
         print a, b ;
         exit
       }' >> "$bi_conf"
done < input_file
```

Here the awk script prints its output and exits as soon as it finds the match.  This terminates the `tail -n0 -f` pipeline and the shell while loop moves on to the next line of `input_file` (and starts a new `tail | awk` pipeline).

BTW, the `-v a="$a" -v b="$b"` is how you pass shell variable `$a` into **awk** variable `a` and shell variable `$b` into awk variable `b`.   Alternatively, you could `export a b` in shell (so that they're exported to the environment visible to child processes) and then use `ENVIRON["a"]` and `ENVIRON["b"]` in awk.

If I knew more about `input_file` and the `a` and `b` variables, it's quite likely the entire thing could be done in `awk`. or `perl`.

---

Alternatively, you could do it with just `bash` and `grep`.  e.g.

```bsh
while read -r a b ; do
  tail -n0 -f "$bi_log" | grep -q -m 1 'Processing Data ended'
  echo "Found"
  echo "$a $b" >> "$bi_conf"
done < input_file
```

The `-m NUM` option tells grep to exit after `NUM` matches (in this case, NUM=1).  The `-q` option tells grep to be quiet, i.e. produce no output and just return an exit code (0 for success, 1 for failure...but because grep's input is coming from `tail -f` it will keep reading forever until it finds a match).

---

PS: as a general rule of thumb, if you ever finding yourself writing a while/read loop in shell, you should stop and think "I should probably do this in awk/perl/python/anything-but-shell".   And then write it in a more appropriate language.

Shell is great for co-ordinating the execution of text and data processing tools.  It's lousy at doing the processing itself.

See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/7696) for details and examples.

Comment: Note that unless you use recent versions of the GNU implementation of `tail` (which monitors whether its stdout has become a broken pipe), `tail -n0 -f` will only terminate if and when it writes more data after `awk` has terminated. See also [make tail -f exit on a broken pipe](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/416150)

Comment: @case thanks for the detailed answer, and I'm choosing your code in alternate chunk, cause it suits most of my routines.

Comment: yeah, the grep version's better. I should have led with that.  didn't think of it until after i'd done the awk version.   in both versions, though, the general idea is: don't do things in shell syntax that are better done with other languages or tools.